# javascript Cannot read property 'style' of null

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

```
 function showNotes() {

     var ThemeValues = "<%=str3%>"
     if (ThemeValues.value == "MyCity-Social") {

         document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.visibility = "visible";
         document.getElementById("TextBox2").style.visibility = "visible";
         $.blockUI({
             message: $('#divNotes'),
             css: {}
         });
     } else {

         //ERROR
         document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("TextBox2").style.display = "none";

         $.blockUI({
             message: $('#divNotes'),
             css: {}
         });

     }
 }
```

function is declared at top and called on click but error is above desribed and also var ThemeValues do not show value

Comment: It means Javascript is not getting your textbox or getting it as null. document.getElementById("TextBox1") is null.

Comment: Also show your html code

Comment: Do you really have a textbox1 in your HTMl ?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="385px" Height="50px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your textbox control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="385px" Height="50px" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then your code above will works.

And for `ThemeValues` variable there, you won't get a any control value there, because you only assign a string to variable there.

use this instead

```
var ThemeValues = document.document.getElementById("<%=str3%>");
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID%>').style.display = "none"
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("TextBox1").style.display = "none";
```